# get aws credentials from ec2 metadata services in Go

Tags: amazon-web-services, go

How can I make the GO SDK fetch the access keys for `AWS` from the `Instance Metadata Service` (`169.254.169.254`) provided by `AWS`.

I checked the official `AWS SDK` for `go` documentation and there seems to be only ways of fetching the access keys from environment variables, but no credentials retriever from `IMS`.

How is this done in go?

Comment: I took the liberty of rewriting your question so that it didn't ask for suggestions for a library.  those kinds of questions get summarily closed.  LMK if you feel my edit was inaccurate description of your question

Comment: No, it is better this way, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I checked the official AWS SDK for go documentation and there seems to be only ways of fetching the access keys from environment variables, but no credentials retriever from IMS.

You just missed it.  The Go SDK supports the instance metadata service as well as every other common credentials provider.

From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/configuring-sdk.html:

> If you have configured your instance to use IAM roles, the SDK uses these credentials for your application automatically.

You don't have to do anything to configure this.  It should just work.  If you're having problems, make sure that you're not manually configuring some *other* credentials source.

Usually you don't have to do anything more than something like:

```
  sess := session.Must(
    session.NewSessionWithOptions(session.Options{
      SharedConfigState: session.SharedConfigEnable,
    }),
  )
```

And with or without CLI configuration, metadata service, or environment variables, it should just work wherever you run it.

Comment: what would be the right way to get the `credentials` out of this session object?

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve, that leads you to want to get credentials out of a session object?

Comment: II am trying to get the credentials like `AccessKeyID` or `SecretKey` from instance metadata provider.

Comment: If you want to retrieve the credentials directly, there's no reason to use an aws sdk.  In GO, use `net/http` to `http.Get("https://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials")` and then `http.Get` the result which will be specific to the instance profile's role.  Conversely, if you are using an aws sdk, there's no reason to touch the credentials and nothing good can come of it.

Comment: I want to create a `v4.Signer` and I need to pass a credentials object `v4.NewCredentials(cred??)`. How do I get that `creds` object?